# Is there any way to force an ag-grid row to show even though it doesn't meet the Quick Filter criteria?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, grid, ag-grid

I have two ag-grids that I am moving items between; one is a searchable list of available items, and the other is a list of the items that the user has previously chosen to add. Users can add items to the below grid by selecting them from the top grid and clicking "add." They can remove items from the bottom grid by selecting them in the below grid and clicking "remove." Above the top ag-grid, I have a search box that is set as a Quick Filter for that grid.

When a user removes an item from the bottom grid, I want it to show in the top grid, regardless of whether it should be filtered out based on the quick filter.

For example, if the user is searching for "Apple" in the top grid and the results are the following:

- Apple Pie
- Apple Sauce
- Apple Ice Cream

and the list of previously selected items in the below grid is the following:

- Pizza
- Pickles
- Cheese

If the user clicks "Pizza" and clicks "remove," I want the top grid to show

- Pizza
- Apple Pie
- Apple Sauce
- Apple Ice Cream

Even though "Pizza" does not meet the quick filter criteria.

I've read through the [ag-Grid filtering documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/) and can't find a good way to do it. The best I can think of is to use JQuery to add rows to the grid, but then I'll have to keep track of the added/removed rows outside of Angular which could be a headache. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I dont know too much about ag-grid, but I read some of their docs and saw that in one of their examples they set a filter like this ['Argentina', 'Algeria']. Cant you do the same like ['Apple', 'Pizza'] after you click remove?

Comment: I actually did try that by sending setQuickFilter a function that adds "|Pizza" to the filter, but it didn't work - I'm not sure if I was returning the filter in the right format though, maybe I'll try again...

Comment: I saw one filter that was like an array, check the section with the title Example Filter API. There is a button there Set Model ['Algeria, 'Argentina']. Try with that it would be easy to add to the array after you removed from the bottom list...

Answer (score 0):

I would add a hidden column to the top table to flag new additions from the bottom. Then filter on both the search terms OR the presence of this flag.

If you want to clear the additions flag when they change the search criteria you can hook into the `onFilterModified` event.

**EDIT**

Or more simply, you could just copy the current search term to this hidden column when they add the rows to the top table. And clear it via the `onFilterModified` event when they change the search criteria.